# What's the most efficient way to keep growing topological sorted tree acyclic?

Tags: algorithm

I know there are at least two ways.

One way is to every time you add an edge to the acyclic tree, traverse necessary vertices.

The downside is as the tree grows big, the traverse procedure takes more and more time.

Another way is to passively check if the added edge creates a infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where topological sorting comes into this, so here is an answer for where you are just creating links between nodes.

At the beginning suppose that you just have a set of disconnected nodes. As you add links you make nodes into trees by linking them. If you create a link to add two previously separate trees, you are not creating a cycle. If you add a link between two nodes that are already in the same tree, you create a cycle. So you can check for cycles by checking to see if the two nodes you are about to link are already in the same tree.

This is union-find, and an efficient way of doing this is described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused about your mention of topological sorting, because if you do a topological sort you get cycle detection for free, and this is explained in loads of places such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort. You will also get cycle-detection out of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29#Algorithms.

Thinking about this, I wonder if you are trying to do on-line cycle detection in a directed graph. I think I once saw some code for this in something that detected deadlocks produced by user code in Unix - it was iterative and relied on the fact that a process could wait on only one event. I think this corresponds to your "traverse necessary vertices".

There seem to be a number of schemes which rely on maintaining a topological sort order. Then if you add a link which is consistent with the order you know that you have not introduced a cycle. The catch is that if you add a link which is not consistent with the order you have to check for cycles and maintain the order. Three such algorithms are described in http://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/~djp/files/tr0703.pdf